# How to pass environment variables from a string to a bash command

Tags: bash

I have a variable `AAA` which is in this format

```
AAA='BBB=1 CCC=2 DDD=3'
```

How can I use this to set environment variables `BBB`, `CCC` and `DDD` in a command I run (without permanently exporting them to the shell)? That is, I want to use to use the above to do something identical to:

```
# this works correctly: node is run with AAA, BBB, and CCC in its environment
BBB=1 CCC=2 DDD=3 node index.js
```

...however, when I try:

```
# this does not work: AAA=1 is run as a command, so it causes "command not found"
$AAA node index.js
```

...it tries to run `BBB=1` as a command, instead of parsing the assignment as a variable to set in `node`'s environment.

Comment: Variable `AAA` contains `BBB=1 CCC=2 DDD=3`?

Comment: Ya it's a string `BBB=1 CCC=2 DDD=3`

Comment: What I am trying to do is I have a comma separated string `BBB=1,CCC=2,DDD=3` and I want to relay them either using environment variables files or just inject them to commands directly. Not sure what's the best way to accomplish this in bash,

Comment: I suggest: `eval $AAA node index.js`

Comment: Is there anything preventing you from storing the contents of `AAA` as an array, and then pass it as normal command parameters, like `AAA=(BBB=1 CCC=2 DDD=3); node index.js "${AAA[@]}"`?

Comment: @BenjaminW. It's just environment variables passing. `node index.js` is just an example.

Comment: `eval` introduces serious security and correctness issues; if your real command has more complex arguments it can easily corrupt them, and that's among the least harmful impacts. Consider `env "${array[@]}" node index.js` after setting up an array as @BenjaminW proposes earlier.

Comment: If you have the BSD or GNU versions of `env`, you can use `env -S "$AAA" node index.js`.

Comment: I see. Thanks for letting know the `eval` side effects.

Comment: @chepner `env -S` doesn't work on Linux, but `env $AAA node index.js` seems to work on both Linux and MacOS.

Comment: @root `env $AAA node index.js` subjects `$AAA` to pathname expansion, so there's a slight risk of not getting what you expect. A value like `BBB=x -- y` will also not work as expected due to the shell's word-splitting. `-S` lets `env` handle the splitting.

Comment: true, but OP wasn't specific so the simple case is assumed. e.g. if `BBB` had the value `x y=z` it would be no different from `BBB=x` + `y=z`, so you have to assume some kind of escaping to begin with.

Comment: @root, we're building answers to be used but just by the OP but everyone who finds the link later. Better to answer the general case (asking follow-up questions where necessary, and explaining assumptions and limitations explicitly) than to assume a simple case.

Comment: Ya I should probably also specify the conditions of my problem more strictly.

Answer (score 4):

#### If you can, use a different format.

There are several better options:

- An array.

  ```
  envvars=( AAA=1 BBB=2 CCC=3 )
  env "${envvars[@]}" node.js index.js
  ```
- A NUL-delimited stream (the ideal format to use to save environment variables in a file -- this is the format your operating system uses for `/proc/self/environ`, for example).

  - Saving to a file:

    ````
    ```
    printf '%s\0' 'foo=bar' \
                  'baz=qux' \
                  $'evil=$(rm -rf importantDir)\'$(rm- rf importantDir)\'\nLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/tmp/evil.so' \
      > envvars
    ```

    ...or, even more simply (on Linux):

    ```
    # save all your environment variables (as they existed at process startup)
    cp /proc/self/environ envvars
    ```
    ````
  - Restoring from that file, and using it:

    ````
    ```
    mapfile -d '' vars <envvars
    env "${vars[@]}" node.js
    ```
    ````

---

#### But whatever you do, *don't* use `eval`

Remember that `evil` environment variable I set above? It's a good example of a variable that poorly-written code can't set correctly. If you try to run it through `eval`, it deletes all your files. If you try to read it from a newline-delimited (not NUL-delimited) file, it sets another `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable that tells your operating system to load a shared library from an untrusted/untrustworthy location. But those are just a few cases. Consider also:

```
## DO NOT DO THIS
AAA='BBB=1 CCC=2 DDD="value * with * spaces"'
eval $AAA node foo.js
```

Looks simple, right? Except that what `eval` does with it is not simple at all:

- First, before `eval` is started, your parameters and globs are expanded. Let's say your current directory contains files named `1` and `2`:

  ```
  'eval' 'BBB=1' 'CCC=2' 'DDD="value' '1' '2' 'with' '1' '2' 'spaces"' 'node' 'foo.js'
  ```
- Then, `eval` takes all the arguments it's passed, and gloms them all together into a single string.

  ```
  eval "BBB=1 CCC=2 DDD="value 1 2 with 1 2 spaces" node foo.js
  ```
- Then that string is parsed from the very beginning

  ...which means that if instead of having a file named `1` you had a file named `$(rm -rf ~)` (a perfectly valid filename!), you would have a very, *very* bad day.

Comment: So the original process is you would have a `.env` file storing all the env variables. And then you source it and start your processes. The thing is I am using `aws ssm get-parameters` and all I get is a comma separated string and I don't know if I should try to parse it and store to the original `.env` format or not.

Comment: Ahh! That "real question" is probably a lot more tractable. Could you ask a separate question that includes example output from the aws command (ideally with enough detail to know that it does with values that contain commas, quotes, newlines, etc)?

Comment: (It's end of day where I'm at, but if you link that other question in, I'll look at it in the morning).

Comment: Ya I figured maybe I should do that. Lemme ask it in another post. Thanks!

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'd recommend using defanged versions of the dangerous example strings, just in case someone tries them the wrong way. Something like `$(rm /importantFile)` or `$(rm -R /yourHomeDirectory)`.

Comment: Hey @CharlesDuffy, I have created another post in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59597117/parse-a-comma-separated-string-and-save-it-to-a-file-in-bash Cheers and have a great night.

Comment: @GordonDavisson, ...good point. I use `rm -rf ~` specifically as an example in some contexts because it's an attack that works even in situations where `/` can't be used, but that isn't pertinent here.