# Parse a comma separated string and save it to a file in bash

Tags: bash

Is there a way to parse a variable like this `AAA=1,BBB=2,CCC=3` in bash and store it to a file in this format?

```
export AAA=1
export BBB=2
export CCC=3
```

The reason is that I store the environment variables in AWS Parameter Store and when you do `aws ssm get-parameters --names xxx --query "Parameters[0].Value"` you would get a comma-separated string.

Thanks.

Comment: I suggest: `x=AAA=1,BBB=2,CCC=3; export ${x//,/ }`

Comment: How does it represent parameter values that contain special characters (commas, spaces, quotes, backslashes, etc)? If you don't handle those correctly (based on the way it represents them), you're likely to get weird bugs.

Comment: @Cyrus that's so cool. Ya it seems to work as well.

Comment: @GordonDavisson not sure yet. I am testing Parameter Store for api keys and stuff for now so I haven't have those use cases.

Comment: Reading the docs at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ssm/get-parameters.html, the parameter store lets you store JSON. Why use a string at all when you could have a dictionary? `{"AAA": "1", "BBB": "2", "CCC": "3"}` is much easier to parse unambiguously (yes, one needs `jq`, Python, or another tool that provides a compliant JSON parser -- but there are no issues in worrying about how more complex values than `1`, `2` or `3` need to be escaped, as the JSON encoder and parser take care of that for you).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an array:

```
v=AAA=1,BBB=2,CCC=3
IFS=, a=( $v )
for i in ${a[@]}
do
    echo "export $i"
done > filename
```

Comment: Instead of an unquoted expansion, you could use `IFS=, read -a a <<< "$v"`

Comment: This may work correctly for values of `1`, `2` and `3`, but it's nothing remotely like a robust solution. Consider `v='AAA=hello world,BBB=something else'`; you don't need the unquoted `$v` expansion (or the unquoted `${a[@]}` one) splitting `AAA=hello` into a separate word from `world`.

Answer (score 2):

`export` accepts multiple values in bash, so it is sufficient to just replace the comma with a space, and proceed the line with export:

```
v=$(aws ssm get-parameters --names xxx --query "Parameters[0].Value")
echo "export ${v//,/ }" > file
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the shell variable "variable" contains `AAA=1,BBB=2,CCC=3`, then the following will do what you want:

```
echo $variable | tr ',' '\n' > filename
```

The first part `echo $variable |` will send the contents of $variable to the stdin of the next process.

The next part `tr ',' '\n'` will run a process that converts commas in the stream running from stdin to stdout into newlines.

The last part `> filename` will take the stdout from the last part and put it in a file called filename.

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Please add an accompanying explanation to the code

Comment: This does not produce the desired output format, namely each variable proceeded by `export`.

Comment: This does not produce the desired output format, namely each variable proceeded by export:  Hmm, true.

Comment: Ya with a combination of `tr` and `sed` it also works. Thanks for the answer still!

Comment: Well if you have to use sed, you can dispense with tr:  echo $variable | sed 's/,/\n/g;s/^/export /g;s/\n/\nexport /g'

Comment: Quote as `echo "$variable"`, or `AAA=hello * world` has the `*` replaced with a list of files in the current directory before the value ever reaches `tr`.

Answer (score 1):

`sed` can also be used in this case with 2 substitution expressions. The first to add `"export "` at the beginning and the second to replace each `','` with `"\nexport "` resulting in the desired output, e.g.

```
sed 's/^/export /;s/,/\nexport /g'
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ echo "AAA=1,BBB=2,CCC=3" | sed 's/^/export /;s/,/\nexport /g'
export AAA=1
export BBB=2
export CCC=3
```

You can simply redirect to a file to save the results.

**awk**

You can also do the same thing with `awk`, just output each comma-separated field preceded by `"export "`, e.g.

```
awk -F, '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)print "export", $i}'
```

(same result)